# How to get rid of trash in Kohana Pagination urls?

Tags: pagination, kohana, kohana-3, clean-url

i've a question on ko3 framework Pagination module.
I have a route template like this: http://my-site.com/blog/1/page2
Here's the code from my bootstrap.php file:

```
Route::set('blog', 'blog(/<id>(/page<page>))')->defaults(array('controller' => 'blog', 'id' => 1, 'page' => 1));
```

everything works nice, but Pagination library generates dirty urls like
`http://my-site.com/blog/1/page3?kohana_uri=blog%2F1`.

Here's the code that creates the pagination (in Controller_Blog)

```
$pag = Pagination::factory(array('total_items' => $total_posts, 'items_per_page' => 10, 'current_page' => array('source' => 'route', 'key' => 'page')));

$posts = $posts_model->selectPosts($section_id, $pag->offset, $pag->items_per_page);

$this->template->content = View::factory('html/blog', array('pag' => $pag));
```

How can I tell the Pagination module generate clean urls? When I remove trash from url manually, it works too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange error. Try this: echo $pag->uri(2); It should return 'blog/1/page2'

Comment: It returned: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pagination::uri()

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem with Kohana but with your server rewrite rules. If you can update your post with the relevant lines from your server configuration then I'm sure we can figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Your `.htaccess` file has something like this in it: `RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT]` which is fine, but setting the `kohana_uri` GET parameter does absolutely nothing in Kohana 3.x. The rewrite should point to `index.php/$0` or just `index.php`.